# Is there a way to parse a svg file with javascript

Tags: javascript, svg

I am able to read the whole svg block, but I just want the x1 attribute (and input it into an array later). What is the best way to do that? I included a line from the svg file that I want to look at.

I have tried using the filereader class but I'm not sure how to just get x1.

```
<line style = "stroke:rgb(0,20,255)" stroke-width = "1" x1 = "25.53951" y1 = "12.65721" x2 = "27.65919" y2 = "16.0494" />"
```

```
const input = document.querySelector('input[type = "file"]')
input.addEventListener('change',function (e){
  console.log(input.files)
  const reader = new FileReader()
  reader.onload = function(){
    console.log(reader.result)
  }
  reader.readAsText(input.files[0])
}, false)
```

Answer (score 2):

The easiest thing to do in this case would be to parse the XML as a Document and use the usual DOM methods to get what you need.

Try something like this:

```
// const data = ...
const parser = new DOMParser();
const svgDoc = parser.parseFromString(data, 'image/svg+xml');
```

Then you can do something like:

```
svgDoc.querySelector('line').getAttribute('x1');
```